# Perforce uploading on server

Tags: upload, perforce

Hi i have installed perforce on my local machine 
but the problem is that i want to save my files on any server so that my files are saved if i lost my window or even my computer my data should be saved somewhere 
please guide me how to do this

This is my work space

[image]

& here is depot

[image]

but where these files are uploaded?
and how my other team mate will get latest revision of these file on his pc?

Answer (score 1):

Perforce is a client-server system.

You and your team can easily collaborate by installing the Perforce server on a third computer, and both of you then use that server to share your work.

When you make a change, submit it to the server. When your colleague makes a change, he does the same.

To update your workspace with the results of your colleague's latest submitted changes, the Perforce term is 'sync', so each of you will interact with Perforce in the classic 'sync-edit-submit' cycle that works very well.

If you change the same file(s) that your colleague changes, the Perforce sync operation will step you through the process of merging your work with the latest work from the server.

It's a straightforward approach, but you do need to have a central server that you both can reach. And don't forget to backup the server, secure it against threats, etc. The Perforce server is very reliable, but it does require a certain amount of administration.

When you are just getting started, you can set up this configuration with the Perforce server running (as a separate background process) on your own workstation, and you and your colleague can share the server in that fashion.

Then, once you are comfortable with the mechanics, you can simply move the Perforce server software to a separate machine to provide always-on availability when your workstation is shut down, and to ensure that, if your workstation fails, the data on the server is safe. Regardless, whichever machine the server is one, don't forget to put a simple backup regimen in place; the Perforce documentation has clear suggestions for how to set this up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
i have use 1666 
so should i use my domain port number instead of this ??
i have several domains on which my websites are running so should i use any one them?
or it is necessary to create an admin pc server?

Comment: I am beginner in perforce please guide me what port number i should use so that my team mate can get the file i am uploading on perforce

Comment: You can use any port number; 1666 is nice because it is the default and so it is less configuration for your teammates. But, whatever port number (and host name) that you use, you have to configure the firewalls and network switches so that your teammate's computer can connect to the server machine.

Comment: Do you have any link of video or pdf or something through i came to know how make a server pc for perforce ??